# what is the difference between "will do" and "will be doing"

Tags: meaning

This guy and his son are [having a room swap](https://youtu.be/dPzbuEunSLk?t=106), he says

> my son will be
>   moving into here

what is the difference between the expression above and the following (my version)?

> my son will 
>   move into here

Comment: You mean: into this house or apartment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I **will play** tomorrow. Shows what I will do tomorrow.
- **I will be playing** tomorrow. Emphasizes the **activity of playing.**

What will you do tomorrow? Tomorrow I will the city.

What will you be doing tomorrow? Tomorrow I will be leaving the city.

Same thing for will move and will be moving.